# How to determine which string in an array is most similar to a given string?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given a string,

```
string name = "Michael";
```

I want to be able to evaluate which string in array is most similar:

```
string[] names = new[] { "John", "Adam", "Paul", "Mike", "John-Michael" };
```

I want to create a message for the user: "We couldn't find 'Michael', but 'John-Michael' is close.  Is that what you meant?"  How would I make this determination?

Comment: FYI, the fact that you have `string[] names =` means that you don't need `new[]`.

Comment: Please define "similar". That 1 example does not really nail it.

Comment: I'm fine with an algorithm making that determination.  I would be fine with "Mike" as the answer or "John-Michael".  I just wanted something that would make a meaningful suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have the results for your example using the Levenshtein Distance:

```
EditDistance["Michael",#]&/@{"John","Adam","Paul","Mike","John-Michael"}
{6,6,5,4,5}
```

Here you have the results using the Smith-Waterman similarity test

```
SmithWatermanSimilarity["Michael",#]&/@{"John","Adam","Paul","Mike","John-Michael"}
{0.,0.,0.,2.,7.}
```

HTH!

Comment: Introducing the two different similarity tests was great; that's what I needed.  Combined with the other answer I got what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: @Michael You may fine-tune a weighted average of both for your purposes. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

This is usually done using the Edit distance / [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) by comparing which word is the closest based on the number of deletions, additions or changes required to transform one word into the other.

There's an article providing you with a generic implementation for C# [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/05/590814.aspx).

Comment: +1, but I would also recommend that if the user finds a non-alphabetic character in a name, it may be a good idea to split the name along the character, otherwise the Levenshtein distance may be too big for John-Michael compared to Mike or one of the other names.

Comment: @Lirik there's all sorts of changes you can make to Edit distance to make it fit a particular problem, i.e. designate different weights (instead of 1/1/1) to additions and substitutions - if you increased the weight on substitutions the algorithm would "prefer" additions/deletions which would cover the example you just gave imo